# pass generic actual view

Tags: java, android, view

I want to take a screenshot of the application, even if the view will change.

The App takes periodically screenshots.

But I have no idea, how to pass generic the actual view.

I tried to pass `android.R.id.content` and `R.id.content`. But it only takes screenshots of the view, where the function was called.

So can somebody help me?

edit:

further explaination:

I want to create a App, that takes periodically screenshots.
The App should also take screenshots, even if the activity/view change.
For example: 
I click the button for periodically screenshots. Now I click on 2nd Button. It opens a new View. And now the the screenshot function should take screenshots of the actual view.

So what must i pass to the function?
Because with R.id.content the function takes only screenshots from the view, where the button was pressed, even if i already changed the view with the 2nd button.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.  Can you specify what you're trying to do, and what you have tried?

Comment: see edit. sorry i'm not a native speaker.

Comment: no worries, just gotta make sure you're being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by taking a look at the [android-screenshot-library](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/)

Good luck!